# No such module found when importing SQLite in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite

I am trying to import SQLite into an app in Xcode. The version of this app was originally developed using SQLite from the following link (not SQLite3).

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

The library has worked in previous iterations, but now I get an error that says "No such module SQLite" when I try to import the library at the top of the file I want to use it.

I have followed the instructions on the gitHub page and still have trouble with the library. One thing that I notice is that in the file explorer the SQLite.framework files are highlighted in red. I believe this is the source of the problem however, I don't know how to fix this.

File Picture: 
[image: img]
Import Error: 
[image: img]

Comment: What GitHub page? You don't need anything from GitHub to use SQLite3 in Swift. Please [edit] your question and show relevant code, as text, in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like you want to include `SQLite` into your `ReadySetFit` project?  If so, what you *really* need to do is to follow the instructions under the "Installation" section found on the [GitHub repo's main page](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift).  I'm a fan of Cocoapods (because all you'd need to do then is add a Podfile to the folder containing your ReadySetFit project), but there's also SwiftPackageManager or Carthage.

Along with the instructions in the SQLite github repo main page (or README.md), [here's a tutorial on how to add a Podfile to your project](https://medium.com/@soufianerafik/how-to-add-pods-to-an-xcode-project-2994aa2abbf1).

I hope this helps!